# Why was a spam flag on an answer with many links disputed?

Tags: discussion, spam, moderation, disputed-flags

I have been reviewing the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19254634) (already deleted) in low-quality queue and marked it as spam. The original contents of answer aren't available to me, because the user immediately (!) edited them out (so I can't even post a screenshot).

The answer consisted from a handful of broken links to web sites. Those links included both reputable sites (such as CSS-Tricks and Stack Overflow (sic!)) and among other things — links to a couple of suspicious-looking sites about web development I hadn't previously seen.

Personally I consider this an example of *extremely vicious* clever spam — it even had me manually enter those URLs in the address bar to visit them — a feat, rarely accomplished by "proper" link spam. The answer also looks rather dodgy and was posted by a fresh user account. Based on those facts, I marked the answer as spam, but the flag was quickly disputed by a moderator.

Was I in wrong here?

We all know that indiscriminately posting links to sites is considered spam. IMO, riding on off-topic questions, mixing in some reputable websites and posting broken links should have no impact on that. At the very least, the answer (and its creator) deserve a proper investigation.

**EDIT**:

I have followed advice by @BhargavRao and had a better look at individual links after being able to seem them again in @SurajRao's answer.

Most are completely innocuous:

1. stackoverflow.com (no comment)
2. [css-tricks.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3Acss-tricks.com&mixed=0) (a well-established web design resource, probably OK)
3. [scotch.io](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3Ascotch.io&mixed=0) — generic article/multiblogging, seems widely-used here
4. [www.sitepoint.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3awww.sitepoint.com&mixed=0) — same as above
5. [www.egrappler.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3awww.egrappler.com&mixed=0) — same as above

The last three belong to the boring "repository of articles" category, which I personally don't like (I wonder if that affected my judgement) and CSS-Tricks is steadily transforming into the same thing by the looks of it.

`www.egrappler.com` is the sole outlier with only 33 mentions on Stack Overflow (many of which are in poor-quality link-only answers). From the brief look, none of websites have seen substantial suspicious link-related behavior and none look especially spammy.

I guess, this single question already gives those websites more exposure, than any devious spam scheme, so let's consider it solved.

Comment: I disputed your flag. I checked each of the links in the original answer, and all of them were semi reputable to reputable. (One good way to test is, [if the URL has been used widely, it might not be spam](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aegrappler.com&mixed=0)). I usually decline these, but I dunno why I disputed your flag. None of the links posted there were spam.

Comment: @BhargavRao I guess, we have slightly different understanding of "spam". Presence of few reputable domains within the list does not impact my view of that answer (by the same logic, it has a link to stackoverflow itself, so it is automatically legit). More importantly, the answer successfully got me to follow those links, completely unrelated to any specific question on stackoverflow. Whether it was a work of dark SEO, exploit-baiting or just someone clueless, posting his first answer on stackoverflow, it successfully worked as spam.

Comment: All the links there were from reputable sites. Do back check all the links on Stack Overflow in the way I mentioned, and you'll get a hang of what I'm trying to convey. The question clearly asked "Are there any sites / blogs to get the latest updates and trends on Web/UI technologies ?" which the answer provided. In these case, you need to vote to close the question instead.

Comment: @BhargavRao Reputability of website does not magically disqualify links to it from being spam. Only intent matters. By the way, almost half of the [33 links](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aegrappler.com&mixed=0) to eggrapler.com on stackoverflow are link-only answers of dubious quality. That does not look **reputable** at all.

Comment: Please do take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion. It might clear some of your confusion regarding what is spam and what is not. Spam is when you are promoting your product. Here they aren't

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks, I have read the page. I am not familiar with that user, so I don't know if they are promoting they own website or being paid by someone else to promote someone's website, or what they goals are in general. In fact, I can easily imagine a group, using astroturfing to artificially inflate page views without disclosing their methods to website owners. Or maybe, it's just me being overly paranoid :) The point is — I am not debating your decision. In fact, if I were in your position, I wouldn't do any differently. It is the user's actions, that  attracted my curiosity.

Comment: Exactly, if you are not able to pinpoint that a user is not a spammer, then   always go for VLQ/NAA. In this case, the user added the answer because the question was at fault. Anyway, glad that you understood. Take care the next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the edit revision:

[image]

It looks like the poster removed the links before the Moderator could get to it. Also the links in the first revision are not really spam links. 
<s>The final post did not have any links and *technically* wasn't spam and your flag was marked as disputed.</s> This was a link only answer and 
after OP removed the links there was no real answer and was nothing more than a meaningless comment.

**Update**: It looks like your question alerted the Mod who rolled back the revision and the whole post(question + answer) is now deleted.

It's a borderline scenario and disputed flags don't count as wrong flag.

Comment: Yes, it *was* a wrong flag because all the sites there are quite reputable ones. They have been used many times all over the place. Just because a user hasn't seen a website, it doesn't make the site a spam site.

Comment: Ah I see.. will update my answer

Comment: Still a little suspicious that a "look here for answers" answer on Stack Overflow contained a link to Stack Overflow. Someone was certainly copy-pasting some random links :/

Comment: @Gimby true.. may be worth r/a flag or spam if it is a repeated offense.. I would be inclined to go for vlq or na for one off posts